# ESTA application paperwork

Tags: air-travel, paperwork, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, uk-citizens

My wife and I flew from Toronto Pearson, Canada to Tampa Florida, USA in November 2015.  We are British citizens, resident in Canada, with official Permanent Resident status.  We completed ESTAs.  We are flying again in April this year.

Should I be in possession of some paperwork, or can I just mention our application from 2015 when we check in at Pearson?

Answer (score 2):

All you need is your passports - check-in agents will look up your ESTA electronically.

Just keep in mind ESTAs are only valid for two years, but if it is valid on the day you're flying to the US, you'll be totally fine. And again, no extra paperwork needed